# Parsing JSON data into an array for a C3.js chart

Tags: javascript, json, c3.js

I'm sending a json variable from django to C3.js in this format:

```
{
   datetime.date(2015, 5, 1): 22792461.479999978, 
   datetime.date(2015, 6, 1): 24807797.38999998, 
   datetime.date(2015, 7, 1): 25261456.609999962
}
```

I need to extract the values and compile them into an array ready for use by c3.js. Here's my script:

```
<script>
   {% include "croydon_dashboards/dashboard_includes/gb_locale.html" %}

   var row_value = {{ row_value }};
   var sum_list = [];

   for(var i in row_value)
      sum_list.push(row_value[i])

   sum_list = JSON.stringify(sum_list);

   var chart = c3.generate({
       data: {
          columns: [
              sum_list
          ],
          type: 'bar'
       },
        bar: {
           width: {
              ratio: 0.5
           }
       }
   });
</script>
```

Hard coding values into the chart works, so I know the c3.js is right, but there's something wrong with the way I'm building the array.

I know that there's an answer here: [JSON Data doesn't show on c3.js bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277178/json-data-doesnt-show-on-c3-js-bar-chart)

but I'm new to javascript and can't work out how to parse the json that I'm working with.

Comment: Why are you stringifying the list `sum_list = JSON.stringify(sum_list);` ?

Comment: I don't know :( I'm just trying to find ways to make the values work, without success.

Comment: @woodbine, with the provided JSON, what are you supposed to produce? one row, or one column?

Comment: I'm trying to build a single list with the values from the json as follows: [22792461.479999978, 24807797.38999998, 25261456.609999962]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to *JSON.stringify()* your data to use it with c3.
But you may have to *JSON.parse()* it to make it look like this:

```
var row_value = {
   "2015-05-01": 22792461.479999978, 
   "2015-06-01": 24807797.38999998, 
   "2015-07-01": 25261456.609999962
};
```

And don't forget to add text label at the beginning of data array:

```
// This first value of array if the name of your data
 var sum_list = ['something'];
```

The rest of your code works.

```
 for(var i in row_value)
    sum_list.push(row_value[i])


 var chart = c3.generate({
     data: {
        columns: [
            sum_list
        ],
        type: 'bar'
     },
      bar: {
         width: {
            ratio: 0.5
         }
     }
 });
```

See **[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/3q91zh6y/1/)**.